# How should I use Angular services with factories for code reuse?

Tags: angularjs, factory, angular-services

I have some Angular Controllers where there's always the need to store an array of items, push elements to it and make it accessible.

I thought then I could have a `ServicesModule` with a **factory** offering such service.

So I got this service declaration:

```
angular.module('ServicesModule',[]);

    angular.module('ServicesModule')
        .factory('newOrdersService', function($rootScope,$http) {

            var newOrder = [];
            return {
                getOrder: function() {return newOrder;},
                addItem:    function(item) {newOrder.push(item);}
            };
        });
```

I got this controller example where I use the service:

```
angular.module('app',['ServicesModule']);


angular.module('app').
  controller('MainController', function($scope, $http, newOrdersService){

      $scope.order = newOrdersService.getOrder();
      $scope.addItem = newOrdersService.addItem();
  });
```

However I can't get it working, seems like using either `getOrder` or `addItem` from the service won't make any effect.

What am I doing wrong?

I offer a [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1iceGuS8gYHIMhxgGnV?p=preview):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I forked your plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/I5dwHNN6iffAXdA0t5g4?p=preview)

You can bind your scope variables directly to a function.

```
$scope.addItem = newOrdersService.addItem;
```

Alternately:

```
$scope.addItem = function(item){
    newOrdersService.addItem(item);
}
```

`$scope.addItem = newOrdersService.addItem()` doesn't work as this will only run your addItem once when the controller is loaded.

And when you add a new item, it's important that you create a new object, or else the objects inside your array will continue being bound to the ng-models (and changed when you enter something into the text inputs).

Comment: And just another point of interest, you could just do `addItem: newOrder.push.bind(newOrder)`

Comment: Creating a new object? I get you point, but isn't that what services are used for, create dependency isolation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just meant a new javascript object, as in addItem({name: 'MyNewObject'});

Comment: I mean that such functions will only provide a service and anything received will be indistinct to the service

Comment: You could also do `$scope.service = newOrdersService` and use your service functions directly in the view: `service.addItem(...)`

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if you're misunderstanding what I mean by object? you had ng-model="item.name" and addItem(item), but this way the ng-model would continue changing item, even though you had put it inside an array in your service, as objects in javascript are reference bound. Therefore the need for addItem({name: item.name}). angular.copy() could also work.

Comment: Yep, I know what a JavaScript object is. But as I've read and understood, services are used to prevent this problem you're mentioning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71635/discussion-between-diegoaguilar-and-kjell-ivar).